# How to return Text Message in Netty Stomp over WebSocket Chat sample?

Tags: netty

I am not familiar with Netty Stomp module and I am running the Stomp over WebSocket Chat sample, every thing is fine, but I found that the message from server is type of Binary Message, in Chrome console.

How to change the Binary Message to Text Message, which should be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `text` as the `context-type` it should use `TextWebSocketFrame`.